# Almost everywhere equality of r.v.'s , based on information on mean values.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Let $X, Y$ be two random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$, where $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal{E})$. We assume that:

1. $\mathcal{E}$ is closed on intersections, i.e. $A\cap B\in \mathcal{E}$ for $A,B \in \mathcal{E}$,
2. $E(|X|)<+\infty$ and $E(X)=E(Y)$,
3. $E(X1_A)=E(Y1_A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal{E},$ where $1_A$ denotes the characteristic function of the set $A$.

Prove that $X=Y$ almost everywhere (with respect to the probability measure $P$).

Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, where $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\pi$-system to show that $\mathbb{E}(X1_A)=\mathbb{E}(Y1_A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal{F}$.
2. Use the fact that if $X,Y\in L^1$, then $X=Y$ a.e. iff (1) holds.

Comment: Thanks a lot @d.k.o for the answer. My only issue is why for $(A_n)$ pairwise disjoint sets of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $E(X1_{A_n})=E(Y1_{A_n})$ for all  $n$ we get $E(XI_A)=E(YI_A)$ for $A$ to be the union of $A_n$'s (i am aware that $1_A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{A_n}$ but there is no positivity in order to use Beppo Levi thm).

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Use the DCT: $\mathbb{E}[X1_{\bigcup A_n}]=\mathbb{E}[\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N X1_{A_n}]=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb{E}[X1_{A_n}]=\sum\mathbb{E}[Y1_{A_n}]$

Comment: Done @d.k.o. ! The whole thing is based on the disjointness of the A_n's, thanks a lot!